# Bulk insertion elasticsearch exception

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch throwing exception while I am reindexing Elasticsearch logs using bulk request API. I am not able to figure out why I am getting this exception. because, this exception I am getting for only few logs.

I'm using node and Elasticsearch version = 6.4.2

exception elasticsearch throwing

```
{"errors":true,"items":[{"index":{"_id":"AWzb9ZeO21aZ6NaDKVvL"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzb9ZfCKk72FRdsT2Jv"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWy46kBGKk72FRdsNYmB"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzRvtZxKk72FRdsSBQ6"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzXHvUn21aZ6NaDJgcs"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzApC3VKk72FRdsOrRT"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzGDMIt21aZ6NaDGat0"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzLKfXcKk72FRdsQwZJ"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWzGP2rKKk72FRdsPz0w"}},{"index":{"_id":"AWy7xTiX21aZ6NaDEqTa"}}]}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: the exception I mentioned above...that's elasticsearch throwing only...which is more confusing.